# UICollectionView not able to scroll to see the entire cell in the last row

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am adding collection view inside UIView. At the first, I can scroll to the end of the cell but when i am clicking the button in the view, i can't scroll to see the entire cell in the last row.

Comment: Can you Please show some code that what you have done?

Comment: Most likely there's a `contentSize` or `autolayout` related issue